# Angular 2 Material md-chips color attribute not working

Tags: angular, colors, md-chip

When i try to style my md-chips with the color attribute nothing happens. According to the guide https://material.angular.io/components/component/chips this has to work. All my other elements style without problems.

```
<md-chip-list>
    <md-chip color="primary"> Chicken </md-chip>
    <md-chip color="warn"> Table </md-chip>
    <md-chip color="accent"> Tree </md-chip>
    <md-chip> Eight </md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

Result:[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview), the chips are only colored when the `selected` attribute is set to `true` :

```
<md-chip color="accent" selected="true">Chicken</md-chip>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set the md-chip color dynamically by using ngStyle

```
<md-chip-list>
 <md-chip *ngFor="let item of itemList" [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: item.color }">
{{ item.name }}
</md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

Comment: ngStyle is a directive in Angular 2

Comment: This is the right way to do it, if you want to self-define chip colors.

Answer (score 3):

Right now (24 Sep 2017), this is not working. Even on the example in the docs isn't working

[image]

I was forced to use a CSS property:

```
<md-chip color="primary" [selected]="true" style="background-color: #986f37">Content here</md-chip>
```